# Undo removed remote branches with git push --mirror

Tags: git, github

I accidentally ran this command: `git push --mirror`, and now most branches in GitHub are lost. How can I get them back? What information I need to put here?

Comment: I've never heard of this behaviour happening. Could you add some more details?

Answer (score 1):

If they are lost on the local repo (as remote tracking branches, in  the "remotes" namespace), a simple `git fetch` should be able to get them back.

If they are lost on the server side, accessing the server and looking into the [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) should be enough to at least see were the HEADs of the various branches were before the push.

Comment: It was hosted on GitHub. How can I run `git reflog` there?

Comment: Now I just have `master` and `develop` in local and remote. `production`, and the rest, are gone in both local and remote.

Comment: @Victor start by a `git fetch`. If a `git branch -avvv` doesn't show you the remote branches, then contact GitHub support.

Comment: yeah, doesn't show. Any other ways other than contacting GitHub? Thanks.

Comment: @Victor check what `git reflog` returns locally. Also check what `git ls-remote origin` returns.

Comment: Thanks VonC. Recovered from production server. Thanks again.